# html css - Text alignment for li

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Chapter One - This is chapter one text text text text text text text text</li>
</ul>
```

[image: actual result]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you edit the HTML at all?

Comment: @Graham Yeah, you can edit anything. I'm just trying to get it look nicely lined up.

Comment: What do you want to do here? Why use list at all? This looks like a paragraph or multiple paragraphs following a heading. Am I correct?

Comment: @amn Well I'm listing a table of chapters with some information on it. I'm still in the process of learning so I don't know which is currently the best way. I was going to use a table instead.

Comment: You mean you want to structure a TOC (Table Of Contents), like in a beginning or end of a book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a definition list (`<dl>`) instead of an unordered list:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Chapter One</dt>
    <dd>This is chapter one text text text text text text text text</dd>
</dl>
```

Now you can float both `<dt>` and `<dd>` left to bring them next to eachother and you can give `<dd>` a specific width.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L4Zem/

Comment: @veelen, yes: "*Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, **or any other groups of name-value data**.*" (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dt-element )

Comment: But wouldn't a header be more appropriate here? In this case, the value says nothing about the name, and the name nothing about the value.

Comment: We don't know what the value contains, but I assumed it as some small summary of the chapter. The, it definetly saus something about the name

Answer (score 4):

An inline-block element with a set maximum width and corrected vertical alignment is all you need.

Markup snippet:

```
<ul>
    <li>Chapter One - <span class="desc">This is chapter one text text text text text text text text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Stylesheet snippet:

```
span.desc {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 10em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The `10em` maximum width is my chosen example value, adjust it according to preference.

Answer (score -1):

try
`ul li {

  text-indent:-50px;

  padding-left:50px;

}`
text-indent with negative value will move first-line left and whole padding-left will shift everything else back

here is a http://jsfiddle.net/edv7d/

Comment: But you need to guess at the width of "Chapter One -"

Comment: Assuming `list-style-position` is outside, not inside.

Comment: both of you are right, it would be nicer if instead of an unordered list  it may be changed to more semantically correct tags like dt,dd